# JavaScript nested for-loop to add values to an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have encountered a situation in my code where I have three java script variables in which two are arrays and one is a single string variable. The following are their structure:

```
var selectedUser = $('#Employees_SelectedValue').val(); //It has one one value "12121"
var selectedCountries = $('#Countries_SelectedValue').val();  //It has multiple values ["IND", "USA"]
var selectedSourceSystems = $('#SourceSystems_SelectedValue').val(); //It has multiple values ["SQL", "ORACLE", "MySQL"]
```

What I have to do is to add these values in a class on the basis of selectedUser such as User is same for all the values but the remaining two are different as:

```
var userSettings = { userName: selectedUser, userCountry: selectedCountries, userSourceSystem: selectedSourceSystems };
```

The situation is to add the values from this class into an array in such a way that every userCountry and userSourceSystem will come as a single entity such as:

```
{ userName: "12121", userCountry: "IND", userSourceSystem: "SQL" },
{ userName: "12121", userCountry: "USA", userSourceSystem: "ORACLE" },
{ userName: "12121", userCountry: "", userSourceSystem: "MySQL" }
```

I'm trying the approach of nested-for loop to handle this scenario like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < selectedCountries; i++)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < selectedSourceSystems; j++)
            {
                userSettings.userName = selectedUser;
               //Add i and j values
            }
        }
```

Please suggest an effective approach other than this.

Comment: Please at first differentiate *class*,*object* and *array* . youve mixed them up a bit...

Comment: you have made an object userSettings and then treating it like an array userSetting[0] . what are you trying to do.

Comment: This is not valid syntax -> `{"12121", "IND", "SQL"}`. error would be "Unexpected token ,"

Comment: Sorry guys, fixed the content. Got a little confused between C# and Javascript but the question is to get the values of userCountry and userSourceSystem as single record with the userName.

Comment: @sahil sharma now it makes more sense. updated answer to fullfill your wanted structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may set up a 3×n matrix ( a 2d array) and rotate it by 90 degrees:

```
var matrix = [[selectedUser],selectedCountries,selectedSourceSystems];

var result =
   Array(//set up a new array
     matrix.reduce((l,row)=>Math.max(l,row.length),0)//get the longest row length
   ).fill(0)
   .map((_,x)=> matrix.map((row,i) => row[i?x:x%row.length] || ""));
```

[Result](http://jsbin.com/moyopihina/1/edit?console)

If result should contain objects, then map the 2d array to objects:

```
var objects = result.map(([a,b,c])=>({userName:a,userCountry:b,userSourceSystem:c}));
```

[result](http://jsbin.com/sonuqayati/1/edit?console)

Small explanation:

```
row[i?x:x%row.length] || ""
```

Actually does the following:

```
If were in the first row ( i=0 ) ("12121")
  take whatever value of the array (x%row.length), so basically always "12121"
if not, try to get the value of the current column(x)
  if row[x] doesnt exist (||) take an empty string ("")
```

---

A more basic approach:

```
var result = [];
for(var i = 0,max = Math.max(selectedCountries.length,selectedSourceSystems.length);i<max;i++){

  result.push({
    userName:selectedUser,
    userCountry:selectedCountries[i]||"",
    userSourceSystem:selectedSourceSystems[i]||""
  });
}
```

[result](http://jsbin.com/pequhotivo/edit?console)

Comment: That's what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot buddy. Like you have calculated the max length and iterate the loop until it is greater than 0, I was trying the same thing using nested for loops But this approach seems simpler and efficient. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be better to restructure your `userSettings` object in more natural way:

```
userSettings: {
    name: "userName",
    countries: ["USA", "IND"],
    userSourceSystems: ["MySQL", "Oracle"]
}
```

Then you can fill it with settings from your inputs like this

```
for (item in selectedCountries)
    userSettings.countries.push(item)

for (item in selectedCountries)
    userSettings.userSourceSystems.push(item)
```

Comment: Theres no need to *fill* , you can simply put it in.